# Is there a way to make a 32-bit variant of port under an amd64 system?

Tags: freebsd

Is there a way to make a 32-bit package variant of mysql-client, for example ? Because I need some libraries for some binary software, and it would be good to maintain them from ports instead of making them manually.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there are several ways. The most straight foward would probably be to setup a 32bit chroot or jail and build the package in there via make package. Another way is to use one of the many tools in the ports-mgmt category, such as tinderbox or poudriere which are designed for building packages.